# SET ANSI_NULL Behavior

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
-- Query1
SELECT 'StackOverFlow' AS Statement11
WHERE 'Name' IN ('S','Q', 'L', 'Name', NULL);
-- Query 2
SELECT 'StackOverFlow' AS Statement12
WHERE 'Name' NOT IN ('S','Q', 'L', NULL);
```

Why do Query 1 return results but Query 2 does not return any result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in
>   column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL
>   returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.

Now, if you were to use

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
-- Query1
SELECT 'StackOverFlow' AS Statement11
WHERE 'Name' IN ('S','Q', 'L', 'Authority', NULL);
-- Query 2
SELECT 'StackOverFlow' AS Statement12
WHERE 'Name' NOT IN ('S','Q', 'L', NULL);
```

The second query would return a result.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4095)

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value
>   evaluate to UNKNOWN. When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, comparisons of all
>   data against a null value evaluate to TRUE if the data value is NULL.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Damien_The_Unveliever

from [IN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared
>   to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null
>   values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

Comment: Might also be worth putting in some info from the [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation (e.g. it has a specific warning re: `NULL`s)